# Install Ubuntu on Windows 7 PC from a USB created on a Mac

Tags: system-installation, usb, windows-7, usb-drive, mac

I want to wipe the hard drive on my PC and then install Ubuntu. The only other working machine that I have is a Mac.

I am wondering how I could install Ubuntu onto a flash-drive and then install it onto the PC.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make an Ubuntu bootable USB drive for a PC using Mac?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454041/make-an-ubuntu-bootable-usb-drive-for-a-pc-using-mac)

Answer (score 0):

I would classify this question as Mac related really, but nonetheless, here's how you can do it:

You can use [**UNetbootin**](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) for Mac to create bootable USBs. [Here's the link to download it for Mac](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/unetbootin-mac-latest.zip).

It is a pretty straightforward application, and there should be several [guides and screenshots](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) on how to use it. Here's the jist of it: Install it. Use the **Discimage** option to point to your downloaded Ubuntu .iso file. Choose your USB flash-drive from the list of attached devices. Hit OK. This will create the bootable Ubuntu USB stick.

*Note: you will only be able to use this bootable Ubuntu USB stick on all PCs except Macs. If you want to install Ubuntu on a Mac, you'll need to create a bootable USB [using another method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick).*

<sub>Source: [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick#UNetbootin_.28Automated.2C_graphical_approach.29)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I Tried to create a USB installation media recently on a Mac, and tried a couple of times to follow instructions but could not get a bootable result.

I ended up creating it on another system.

I would suggest doing the same, or create a installation DVD instead.