# Create a bootable usb in a mac for a non-mac system

Tags: live-usb

I'm trying to make a bootable USB stick on Mac OS X and get the Acer Aspire accept it. Windows 7 is gone completely on the Acer and Ubuntu 13.04 or 13.10 does not start at all. I tried to make a Mac-bootable USB stick, but I cannot.

Comment: @jkt123 this and that is totally different. In that question OP is asking why creating following the instructions he fails. This is about booting an USB in a non-mac system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make an Ubuntu bootable USB drive for a PC using Mac?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/454041/make-an-ubuntu-bootable-usb-drive-for-a-pc-using-mac)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the article that you want is: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

But in case you do not want to look it up, here it is:

Note: this procedure requires that you create an .img file from the .iso file you download. It will also change the filesystem that is on the USB stick to make it bootable, so backup all data before continuing.

Tip: Drag and drop a file from Finder to Terminal to 'paste' the full path without risking typing errors.

1. Download Ubuntu Desktop
2. Open the Terminal (in /Applications/Utilities/ or query Terminal in Spotlight).
3. Convert the .iso file to .img using the convert option of `hdiutil`.  Example:

   ```
   hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img ~/path/to/ubuntu.iso
   ```

   Note: OS X tends to put the .dmg ending on the output file automatically.
4. Run `diskutil list` to get the current list of devices.
5. Insert your flash media.
6. Run `diskutil list` again and determine the device node assigned to your flash media (e.g. `/dev/disk2`).
7. Run `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN` (replace N with the disk number from the last command; in the previous example, N would be 2).
8. Execute `sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m` (replace `/path/to/downloaded.img` with the path where the image file is located; for example, `./ubuntu.imgor ./ubuntu.dmg`).

   Using /dev/rdisk instead of /dev/disk may be faster.  If you see the error `dd: Invalid number '1m'`, you are using GNU dd. Use the same command but replace `bs=1m` with `bs=1M`.

   If you see the error dd: /dev/diskN: Resource busy, make sure the disk is not in use. Start the 'Disk Utility.app' and unmount (don't eject) the drive.
9. Run `diskutil eject /dev/diskN` and remove your flash media when the command completes.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to experiment with all the options, but did not succeed, and I was aware of this link: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx and On a Mac, when you change the file name:.iso to .img, it will automatically convert