# How to create a bootable thumbdrive using MacOS

Tags: boot, live-usb, 20.04, usb-drive, usb-installation

My ubuntu machine died and I need to install a new OS on that machine using another laptop I have which is a MacOS machine. I am having trouble finding good info on how to create a bootable thumbdrive to install Ubuntu 20.04 onto my Dell machine, using my Mac machine. Anyone know the best way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make an Ubuntu bootable USB drive for a PC using Mac?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454041/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try the Ubuntu Tutorials written for that purpose

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-ubuntu/14011
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-windows/14020
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-macos/14016

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-burn-a-dvd-on-windows/14008
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-burn-a-dvd-on-macos/14015
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu/14022

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-create-an-sdcard-with-ubuntu-server-for-a-raspberry-pi/14646

Traditionally tutorials once written when to https://ubuntu.com/tutorials however now the discourse site appears to be becoming the place for tutorials